# Why is my bash script breaking on an empty space?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, echo

I have a shell script that is breaking on a space on line 42 between Virtualhost and the *. As a result, the only thing that is echo'd to console is

```
<VirtualHost
```

What I want to happen is for my entire string to be echo'd to the console.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/web
        ServerName web.localhost
        <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Includes
        AllowOverride All 
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all 
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my script for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script should be used to automate the web site installation

checkFileForString ()
{
    # $1 = file
    # $2 = regex
    # $3 = text to be added
    declare file=$1
    declare regex=$2
    declare file_content=$( cat "${file}" )

    if [[ ! " $file_content " =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo "$3" #>> $file
    else
        replaceStringInFile $file $regex $3
    fi
}

replaceStringInFile ()
{
    # $1 = file
    # $2 = old string
    # $3 = new string

    sed -i -e 's|${2}|${3}|' $1
}

createFile ()
{
    # $1 = file
    declare fileToCheck=$1

    if [ ! -f $fileToCheck ]; then
       touch $fileToCheck   
    fi
}

# Add vhosts to httpd-vhosts.conf
echo "Adding vhosts to httpd-vhosts.conf"
currentFile="/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
currentRegex="<VirtualHost\s[*]:80>\s+DocumentRoot\s/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/web\s+ServerName\sweb.localhost"
newText="<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/web
    ServerName web.localhost
    <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/web>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
"

checkFileForString $currentFile $currentRegex $newText
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put variables in double quotes to expand them without word splitting and wildcard expansion.

```
checkFileForString "$currentFile" "$currentRegex" "$newText"
```

Another problem in your script is the `replaceStringInFile()` function. Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes. So it should be:

```
sed -i -e "s|${2}|${3}|" "$1"
```

Comment: And for further reading, [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and the [guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html).  Also, consider using [`printf`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=printf&sektion=1) instead.