# path variable containing * in ksh

Tags: ksh, filepath, variable-expansion

I am working on a Mac. I have a directory called **1. A** (with a white space in the name) inside the directory **Test**

Now, the following ksh script

```
typeset MyPath=1.* 
print $MyPath 
cd $MyPath 
pwd 
cd .. 
touch $MyPath/File.txt
```

produces

```
1. A
Test/1. A
touch: 1.*/File.txt: No such file or directory
```

Thus it looks like both print and cd recognize the pattern "1. A" but touch does not. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my bash script breaking on an empty space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789687/why-is-my-bash-script-breaking-on-an-empty-space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always quote your variables unless you want the expansion to be split on spaces and wilcards to be expanded.

```
MyPath=$(IFS= echo 1.*)
print "$MyPath"
cd "$MyPath"
pwd
cd ..
touch "$MyPath/File.txt"
```

`echo 1.*` expands the wildcard. The assignment `IFS=` disables word splitting by clearing the field separator variable (this is needed in case the name has multiple consecutive spaces, otherwise they would be merged).

Comment: Unfortunately, I obtain exactly the same output when I use the quotes.

Comment: Did you add the quotes on all the lines?

Comment: I see the problem. Wildcards aren't expanded when you assign a variable, so `MyPath=1.*` just sets the variable to the literal string `1.*`, not the matching filename.

Comment: See my change to the assignment